# Исключение при загрузке данных из xml

Tags: java, xml, javafx, исключения, загрузка

Я создал JavaFX проект и в контроллере главного окна реализую метод, в котором при нажатии на кнопку должно создаться новое модальное окно, но при при загрузке данных из xml файла выбрасывается исключение. Что не так в моем коде?

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/sample.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Телефонная книга");
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 300));
    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}


package sample.controllers;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainController {


public void removePeople(ActionEvent event) {
    System.out.println("remove");
}

public void addPeople(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml"));


    stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 200, 200));
    stage.setTitle("Добавление контакта");
    stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
    stage.show();
}
}



sample.xml
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"  minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="382.0" prefWidth="602.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.controllers.MainController">
....


modalWindowAddPeople.fxml
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox fx:controller="sample.controllers.ModalWindowAddPeople" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="197.0" prefWidth="421.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
```

Исключения:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at     javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
 .... 
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
.... 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at sample.controllers.MainController.addPeople(MainController.java:22)
... 58 more
```

Comment: Приведите как можно больше информации по исключению: сообщение об ошибке, трассировку стэка, тип.

Comment: Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
....
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
 at sample.controllers.MainController.addPeople(MainController.java:22)

Comment: Добавьте это в текст вопроса. Его можно отредактировать с помощью кнопки «править» под вопросом.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить слэш: `getClass().getResource("/fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml")` если не поможет, то расскажите в какой папке лежит `modalWindowAddPeople.fxml` и попадает ли он в сборку.

Comment: слэш не помог. Файл лежит в src/sample/fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml. Все контроллеры лежат в src/sample/controllers/

Comment: Перенесите в `src/resources/fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml`

Comment: Да, это помогло. Т.е. эта проблема заключалась в том, что пакет в src файле назывался неправильно??? Нужно всегда называть пакет "resources"?

Comment: Описал суть происходящего в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Class.getResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) возвращает ресурс по имени. Метод ищет файл по пути относительно класса, от которого метод вызывается.

Например, класс `Main` находится в пакете `sample`, файл `sample.xml` находится в пакете `sample/fxml`. Соответственно, из класса `Main` поиск ресурса по относительному пути срабатывает корректно:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/sample.fxml"));
```

Ошибка же происходит при втором обращении. Класс `MainController` находится в пакете `sample.controllers`. Соответственно, при вызове из него:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml"));
```

метод будет искать ресурс в расположении `sample/controllers/fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml`, в то время как файл находится в пакете `sample/fxml`.

Пути решения:

- прописывать каждый раз относительный путь от класса, из которого вызывается метод:

  ```
  getClass().getResource("../fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml")
  ```
- обращаться к ресурсам через слэш по абсолютному пути:

  ```
  getClass().getResource("/sample/fxml/modalWindowAddPeople.fxml").
  ```

Судя по всему, Вы используете для сборки Maven. По-умолчанию, при сборке файлы из каталога `src/resources` перемещаются в корень (поведение по-умолчанию может быть переопределено настройками), соответственно, если файл лежит в папке `src/resources/fxml`, то к нему можно обратиться по абсолютному пути `/fxml/..`. Папка используется чтобы отделить ресурсы логически от исходного кода.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогли разобраться в этой проблеме!